# PHP preg_replace only latin characters

Tags: php, regex

I need to filter string when I build XML for electronic invoices for Italy.

From specific are accepted only:

```
String1000LatinType
"[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}]{1,1000}"
```

I'm not sube about the range, but I think:

`a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, accented like: `à ò ù è é ì`, `ç` and symbols like: `, . _ - : ; '` and whitespace

I'd like to exclude all others symbols directly from keyboard like: `"£$%&/()=?^°§*+\|/<>` and `tab`

I tried converting with this function but i'm not a guru with regexp:

```
function sanitize($tag) {

$newtag = preg_replace ("/[\p{Latin}A-Z0-9a-z\-\_\.\,\:\;' ]/", "", $tag);

return $newtag;

}

$tag = "Qwerty 12345 £$%&/()=?^ èéòàùì +*°ç.,-_<>\/l'èok .,;:";

var_dump(sanitize($tag));
```

Can someone help me?

I'd like to retrieve:

```
Qwerty 12345  èéòàùì ç.,-_l'èok .,;:
```

Comment: with u athe the end I get only unwanted chars....i'd like to stripout there chars

Comment: Wait... It seems PHP does not support `\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}`\

Comment: I'd like to retireve: Qwerty 12345  èéòàùì ç.,-_l'èok .,;:

Comment: See the answer below. If you need more customizations, please let know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems PHP does not support `\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}`. However, you may use a Unicode code point range in your regex. As [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)):

> This block ranges from `U+0080` to `U+00FF`

The [`\p{IsBasicLatin}`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) matches chars from `U+0000` to `U+007F`. So, what you need is to match any char other than a char with code points from `\x00` to `\xFF` + all punctuation and symbols with the exception of those special ones:

```
preg_replace('~(?:[^\x00-\xFF]|(?![.,_\'-])[\p{P}\p{S}])~u', '', $tag)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r2lnIh/1).

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group

  - `[^\x00-\xFF]` - any char but a char in the Unicode code point range of `\x00` to `\xFF`
  - `|` - or
  - `(?![.,_\'-])[\p{P}\p{S}])` - any punctuation (`\p{P}`) or symbol (`\p{S}`) that are not equal to the chars in the `.,_'-` list.
- `)+` - end of group, repeat it 1 or more times.

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/DT2lJ):

```
function sanitize($tag) {
 $newtag = preg_replace('~(?:[^\x00-\xFF]|(?![.,_\'-])[\p{P}\p{S}])+~u', '', $tag);
 return $newtag;
} 
$tag = "Qwerty 12345 £$%&/()=?^ èéòàùì +*°ç.,-_<>\/l'èok .,;:";
var_dump(sanitize($tag));
// => Qwerty 12345  èéòàùì ç.,-_l'èok .,;:
```

Comment: I've inserted a response

Answer (score 0):

After some test, i create this function to fit my purposes:

```
function sanitize_string_xml($string, $opzioni = array()) {

    $chr_map = array(
       // Windows codepage 1252
       "\xC2\x82" => "'", // U+0082⇒U+201A single low-9 quotation mark
       "\xC2\x84" => '"', // U+0084⇒U+201E double low-9 quotation mark
       "\xC2\x8B" => "'", // U+008B⇒U+2039 single left-pointing angle quotation mark
       "\xC2\x91" => "'", // U+0091⇒U+2018 left single quotation mark
       "\xC2\x92" => "'", // U+0092⇒U+2019 right single quotation mark
       "\xC2\x93" => '"', // U+0093⇒U+201C left double quotation mark
       "\xC2\x94" => '"', // U+0094⇒U+201D right double quotation mark
       "\xC2\x9B" => "'", // U+009B⇒U+203A single right-pointing angle quotation mark

       // Regular Unicode     // U+0022 quotation mark (")
                              // U+0027 apostrophe     (')
       "\xC2\xAB"     => '"', // U+00AB left-pointing double angle quotation mark
       "\xC2\xBB"     => '"', // U+00BB right-pointing double angle quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x98" => "'", // U+2018 left single quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x99" => "'", // U+2019 right single quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x9A" => "'", // U+201A single low-9 quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x9B" => "'", // U+201B single high-reversed-9 quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x9C" => '"', // U+201C left double quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x9D" => '"', // U+201D right double quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x9E" => '"', // U+201E double low-9 quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\x9F" => '"', // U+201F double high-reversed-9 quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\xB9" => "'", // U+2039 single left-pointing angle quotation mark
       "\xE2\x80\xBA" => "'", // U+203A single right-pointing angle quotation mark
    );

    $type = isset($opzioni['Type']) ? $opzioni['Type'] : "";    // IsBasicLatin /IsLatin

    $lunghezzaMax = isset($opzioni['LunghezzaMax']) ? $opzioni['LunghezzaMax'] : "";

    if ( $type == "IsBasicLatin" ) {

        $unwanted_array = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                            'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                            'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                            'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                            'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', "ü" => "u", 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );

        $string = strtr( $string, $unwanted_array );

        $string = preg_replace('/[^\x{0020}-\x{007E}]+/u', '', $string);

    }

    if ( $type == "IsLatin" ) {

        $unwanted_array = array(  'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z' );

        $string = strtr( $string, $unwanted_array );

        $string = preg_replace('/[^\x{0020}-\x{007E}\x{00A0}-\x{00FF}]+/u', '', $string);

    }

    //  CONVERTI GLI ACCENTI FUORI DAL RANGE IN APICI AMMESSI:

    $chr = array_keys  ($chr_map); // but: for efficiency you should

    $rpl = array_values($chr_map); // pre-calculate these two arrays

    $string = str_replace($chr, $rpl, html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));




    $string = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(PHP_EOL, " ", $string));

    if ( $lunghezzaMax != "" ) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $lunghezzaMax);
    }

    return $string;

}
```

Usage example:

```
$clear_string = sanitize_string_xml($dirty_string, array("Type" => "IsLatin", "LunghezzaMax" => 60));
```